# Maven Could not resolve dependencies for hadoop project

Tags: maven, hadoop, mapreduce

I wanted to build the sample projects from [hadoop](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/3e) book but I got "Could not resolve dependencies error".
Here is my Error during build:

```
[INFO] Building Chapter 2: MapReduce 3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:0.23.10 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-test:jar:0.23.10 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Chapter 2: MapReduce .............................. FAILURE [1.409s]
[INFO] Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, Example Code ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.819s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 14 12:19:14 EEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/67M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ch02: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.hadoopbook:ch02:jar:3.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:0.23.10, org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-test:jar:0.23.10: Failure to find org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:0.23.10 in https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache.releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

and here is my pom.xml for ch02 project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.hadoopbook</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-meta</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <relativePath>../hadoop-meta/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.hadoopbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>ch02</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <name>Chapter 2: MapReduce</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any idea how can I build this code using maven and what the problem is ?
Thanks

Comment: What was the exact maven command that you ran?

Comment: mvn package -DskipTests -Dhadoop.version=0.23.10

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that Maven can't find the what it is looking for in the remote repository. So when it reaches out to [Apache's Maven repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/) it's just not finding the resources for version 0.23.10 hadoop-test.

Particularly line #8 of the pom file in the question `<relativePath>../hadoop-meta/pom.xml</relativePath>` is directing Maven to look at [`hadoop-meta/pom.xml`](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/3e/hadoop-meta/pom.xml). On line #48 through #50 you'll see the specification for the hadoop-test repository:

```
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
<version>${hadoop.version}</version>
```

That `${hadoop.version}` is the value that you specify in your maven command, ie `0.23.10`.
So then maven goes out to the Apache repo and looks for [hadoop-test v0.23.10](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-test/), which isn't present. So then Maven falls over.

Now if you used a version that is present in the hadoop-test, or if you altered the pom files so that hadoop-test isn't a dependency.

Comment: but it is pointing to a valid repo and I'm using this dependency in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, it turned out it was because of NetBeans adding something to my pom.xml file. Double check nothing was added since previous successful deployments.